# LeafletJS - я хочу переместить контролер зума как я могу это сделать?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs, leafletjs, react-leaflet

LeafletJS - я хочу переместить контролер зума как я могу это сделать ? я знаю что есть элементы управления topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright но я не понимаю как их применить в nextjs.

```
return (<MapContainer
    center={[initialMaps.coord.latitude, initialMaps.coord.longitude]}
    zoom={initialMaps.zoom}
    scrollWheelZoom={true}
    className={`${st.containerMap}`}
>
    <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    {/* <MarkersList list={dataPlaces || []} />
    {coordsUser ? <Marker
        position={[coordsUser.latitude, coordsUser.longitude]}
        icon={new L.Icon({ iconUrl: iconMarker.itsMy })} />
        : null} */}
</MapContainer>)
```

}
[image: Элемент]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если по порядку, то правой кнопкой мыши по объекту и иследовать код (что вы и сделали). Потом там должен быть div с таким классом `leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar leaflet-control`. И дальше прописать в css файле ему стиль. `margin-left: 200px;`. Количество пикселей сами подберите нужное и тогда он переместиться куда вам нужно.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Такой подход к сожалению результатов не дает

Comment: @МаксимКнижник, вы нашли div в котором этот zoom есть?

Comment: да в общем я разобрался ваш подход был верный не работало ииза подключения стилей в некст тоесть если мы подключаем стили через import style from './style.scss' это не работает следует использовать import './style.scss';

Answer (score 0):

В Nextjs eсли мы подключаем стили через "import style from './style.scss'" это не работает следует использовать "import './style.scss'" обязательно ниже import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";